# Why is Torch not working on my VS Studio workspace?

Tags: python, pytorch, compiler-errors, torch

I’m writing this message as I saw all the others but they didn’t help me. I tried to download PyTorch in all the different ways, by creating new environments, etc, but it still not working.

[image]

I've already seen all the other comments already asked but there seems not to be an answer.

Comment: How did you install your libraries (torch and torchvision)?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using are not using the python executable from your environment named "env_pytorch", but the one from `/usr/local/bin`, so pytorch is not installed within this python environment. To use the one from "env_pytorch", you could launch your script with `python3 path_to_your_python_file` or `path_to_your_conda_install/envs/env_pytorch/bin/python3 path_to_your_python_file`.

To change the python interpreter to be used by VSCode to launch the script, check [this link from VSCode doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that there needs to be more information in the question to answer this. Nevertheless, assuming that you are using anaconda on a Mac and are trying to run the python script in the screenshot, here's what I think could help you:

I'll recommend installing PyTorch in your conda environment in your terminal. Open your terminal and activate your conda environment and then copy the install command matching your machine spec from [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/). Once you install that, use this conda environment as your python interpreter in VS code before running the code. [This page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on VS code website describes how to do that, in short just do command+shift+p(⇧⌘P) and select your conda environment. You should be able to run the script after this.